# SOQL: WHERE ID in string variable

Tags: soql

Can you query an object using the IN operator where the value is a variable?

**This works:**

```
stfilter = 'Kansas'
Select ID from LIcense__c where State__c IN (:stFilter)
```

**This however doesn't work:**

```
stfilter = ''Kansas', 'Missouri''
Select ID from LIcense__c where State__c IN (:stFilter)
```

**BUT if I take the same thing and just put it in the query it does work:**

```
Select ID from LIcense__c where State__c IN ('Kansas','Missouri')
```

Do I need to transform the string somehow first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply bind a `List`or `Set` of any type. For example:

```
List<String> stFilterList = new List<String>();
stFilterList.add('Kansas');
stFilterList.add('Missouri');

// Query would be like
Select ID 
FROM LIcense__c 
WHERE State__c IN : stFilterList
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, You can create list or set of values and refer  that List or Set in the SOQL, Simple!

```
For List : 
stFilter= new List<string>();
stFilter.add('Iteam1');
stFilter.add('Iteam2');

For Set:
stFilter= new Set<string>();
stFilter.add('Iteam1');
stFilter.add('Iteam2');

Select ID from LIcense__c where State__c IN :stFilter;
```

If this helped you, Please mark it as best answer!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as answered by others, you need to put them into a list.

You can further improve if required to use `LIKE` also to be used along with `IN` for a list.

```
setAccNames.add('%'+'ABC'+'%');
setAccNames.add('%'+'XYZ'+'%');
setAccNames.add('%'+'RST'+'%');

List<Account> accList = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name LIKE :setAccNames];
```

More on this -->
https://sfdcfanboy.wordpress.com/2016/03/01/use-like-and-in-in-a-single-soql-query/